# Function does not return correct char** pointer

Tags: c, arrays, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//function to change char to upper case
char upper(char ch)
{
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <='z')
        return ch - ('a'-'A');
    else
        return ch;
}

//Function to find words starting with letter and return array of string words
char **find_words(char *str,char letter, int *size)
{
    char **str_arr=NULL;
    int i=0,j=0;
    int ch;
    int len;


    while (str[j] != NULL)
    {
        ch = str[j];
        while (ch !=' ' && ch !=NULL)
            ch = str[j++];

        str[j-1]=NULL;

        ch = upper(str[i]);
        if ( ch == upper(letter))
        {
            (*size)++;
            str_arr = (char **)realloc(str_arr,(*size)*sizeof(char *));
            len = strlen(&str[i]);
            str_arr[*size] = (char *)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));

            strcpy(str_arr[*size],&str[i]);
            printf("\n%s",str_arr[*size]);
        }   
        i=j;
    }

    return str_arr;
}


//Main program to check function find words
void main()
{
    char** str_array=NULL;
    int i,j;
    int size=0;
    char str[] = "Good night go to sleep, Goodman";
    char letter ='g';

    str_array = find_words(str,letter,&size);

    /*
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",str_array[i]);
    }
    */

    printf("\n");
}
```

The function `find_words` works and prints a list of words from dynamic array of strings, but in main program the returned pointer `char **str_arr` become null.

what is the reason? How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Please read up `toupper` - https://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you code has issue with incrementing *size*. Post incrementing might solve your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



//function to change char to upper case
char upper(char ch)
{
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <='z')
        return ch - ('a'-'A');
    else
        return ch;
}

//Function to find words starting with letter and return array of string words
char **find_words(char *str,char letter, int *size)
{
    char **str_arr=NULL;
    int i=0,j=0;
    int ch;
    int len;


    while (str[j] != NULL)
    {
        ch = str[j];
        while (ch !=' ' && ch !=NULL)
            ch = str[j++];

        str[j-1]=NULL;

        ch = upper(str[i]);
        if ( ch == upper(letter))
        {

            str_arr = realloc(str_arr,(*size+1)*sizeof(char *));
            len = strlen(&str[i]);
            str_arr[*size] = malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));

            strcpy(str_arr[*size],&str[i]);
            printf("\n%s",str_arr[*size]);
            //little change here
            (*size)++;
        }   
        i=j;
    }

    return str_arr;
}


//Main program to check function find words
void main()
{
    char** str_array=NULL;
    int i,j;
    int size=0;
    char str[] = "Good night go to sleep, Goodman";
    char letter ='g';

    str_array = find_words(str,letter,&size);


    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",str_array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: In addition it need `*size + 1` here: `str_arr = realloc(str_arr, (*size + 1) * sizeof(str_arr));`

Comment: `str_arr = (char **)realloc(str_arr,(*size)*sizeof(char *));` ==> `str_arr = (char **)realloc(str_arr,(*size + 1)*sizeof(char *));` if you want to access `str_arr[*size]`

Comment: Please get rid of the casts for `malloc/realloc` -

Comment: if ( ch == upper(letter))
  {
   str_arr = (char **)realloc(str_arr,(*size+1)*sizeof(char *));
   len = strlen(&str[i]);
   str_arr[*size] = (char *)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
   
   strcpy(str_arr[*size],&str[i]);
   (*size)++;
  }